# How do I change the "not valid input" text of HTML5 forms

Tags: forms, html, validation

If the input field's type is `email` in an html5 form, and if someone does not input a valid email address, it will say `Please enter an email address.`

Is there a way to change that text without a ton of javascript ? (by a ton of javascript I mean another implementation of that input field validadors written with a lot of javascript that usually depend on jQuery or others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the [validationMessage](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-validationmessage) attribute, but I don't know if any browser honors it.

Here is their example for setting the custom message [setCustomValidity](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity)

In firefox there is also the [x-moz-errorMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input#Error_messages) attribute

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XYgJH/

```
<form>
<input type="email" oninput="check(this)"/>
</form>
<script>
    function check(input){
    if(input.valid){
        input.setCustomValidity('');
    } else {
        input.setCustomValidity('silly duck');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: There's a typo I couldn't fix. In case anyone else is searching it's actually: `x-moz-errorMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has implemented a non-standard attribute: `x-moz-errormessage`

So you can have something like this, where the title text is used when the field is left empty:

```
<input type=“email” required x-moz-errormessage=“Wrong!” title=“Try again”>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox currently supports an attribute `x-moz-errormessage` which replaces the built-in error message.

Otherwise, if you know when a validation is about to be triggered, you might be able to temporarily set a custom invalid state message by using `isValid()` and `setCustomValidity()`.